i'm facing this error when trying tp push my app to play store: Your app declares support for 'riscv64' architecture
i'm facing this error when trying tp push my app to play store:
Your app declares support for 'riscv64' architecture, but the following libraries are missing:[libVisionCamera.so, libc++_shared.so, libcrashlytics-common.so, libcrashlytics-handler.so, libcrashlytics-trampoline.so, libcrashlytics.so, libfabricjni.so, libfb.so, libfbjni.so, libfolly_runtime.so, libgifimage.so, libglog.so, libglog_init.so, libhermes.so, libhermes_executor.so, libhermesinstancejni.so, libimagepipeline.so, libjniPdfium.so, libjscinstance.so, libjserrorhandler.so, libjsi.so, libjsijniprofiler.so, libjsinspector.so, liblogger.so, libmapbufferjni.so, libmodft2.so, libmodpdfium.so, libmodpng.so, libnative-filters.so, libnative-imagetranscoder.so, libreact_codegen_rncore.so, libreact_config.so, libreact_debug.so, libreact_nativemodule_core.so, libreact_newarchdefaults.so, libreact_render_animations.so, libreact_render_attributedstring.so, libreact_render_componentregistry.so, libreact_render_core.so, libreact_render_debug.so, libreact_render_graphics.so, libreact_render_imagemanager.so, libreact_render_leakchecker.so, libreact_render_mapbuffer.so, libreact_render_mounting.so, libreact_render_runtimescheduler.so, libreact_render_scheduler.so, libreact_render_telemetry.so, libreact_render_templateprocessor.so, libreact_render_textlayoutmanager.so, libreact_render_uimanager.so, libreact_utils.so, libreactnativeblob.so, libreactnativejni.so, libreactperfloggerjni.so, libreanimated.so, librninstance.so, librnscreens.so, librrc_image.so, librrc_legacyviewmanagerinterop.so, librrc_native.so, librrc_root.so, librrc_scrollview.so, librrc_text.so, librrc_textinput.so, librrc_unimplementedview.so, librrc_view.so, libruntimeexecutor.so, libsentry-android.so, libsentry.so, libstatic-webp.so, libturbomodulejsijni.so, libucrop.so, libuimanagerjni.so, libworklets.so, libyoga.so]. Update your app to rely on libraries that support 'riscv64' architecture.
'riscv64' architecture is only supported for application targeting WearOS.
push my app to play store

You can create an include filter which will remove all unwanted architectures and only leaves the one you specify https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#gc

so we solved the issue by using version 4.5.2 and removing the ^ from the version


I had this same issue using react-native-vision-camera:^4.3.2.
Upgrade to react-nativ-vision-camera:4.5.2 fix the problem.
